# vue-chartjs vue-class-component chartOptions not working

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-chartjs, vue-class-components

I am busy migrating to vue@2.7 from vue@2.6 and found that during the upgrade for some reason vue-chartjs chartOptions is not working.

I defined my lineChart like this in html:

```
<line-chart v-if="!loading" :chartData="chartData" :options="chartOptions"/>
```

and in my script I defined the chartOptions getter like this:

```
  get chartOptions(): ChartOptions {
    return {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: true,
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          display: false,
        },
      },
    }
  }
```

my chartData getter is defined in a similar manner and I cannot work out why the chartOptions are not being detected properly by vue-chartjs

Comment: Does it return some sort of error or warning in the console?

Comment: Nope no error just doesn't detect the options